# How to not use JavaScript with in the elements events attributes but still load via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

I am currently loading HTMl content via AJAX.

I have code for things on different elements `onclick` attributes (and other event attributes).

It does work, but I am starting to find that the code is getting rather large, and hard to read. I have also read that it is considered bad practice to have the event code 'inline' like this and that I should really do by `element.onclick = foobar` and have `foobar` defined somewhere else.

I understand how with a static page it is fairly easy to do this, just have a script tag at the bottom of the page and once the page is loaded have it executed. This can then attach any and all events as you need them.

But how can I get this sort of affect when loading content via AJAX. There is also the slight case that the content loaded can very depending on what is in the database, some times certain sections of HTML, such as tables of results, will not even be displayed there will be something else entirely.

I can post some samples of code if any body needs them, but I have no idea what sort of things would help people with this one. I will point out, that I am using Jquery already so if it has some helpful little functions that would be rather sweet!

**Small code sample**

This is a sample of code that is loaded via an AJAX request

```
<input type="submit" name="login" value="login" onclick="
if(check_login(this.form)){
  Window_manager.windows[1].load_xml('login/display.php?username=' + this.form.username.value + '&amp;password=' + this.form.password.value);
} else {
  return false;
}">
```

I know this is small sample, but this is the sort of thing I am on about. How can I have this code attached when the content is loaded?

Comment: it looks like a custom code - you must add callback function. Since you're using jQuery in your project anyway why aren't you using jQuery.ajax() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is probably what you are looking for. It will attach click event to  newly created HTML elements, so you don't need to call your .click() with every reload of your update-panel.

Comment: oooh, that is a very fancy function. So I can link a class to an event, and then when ever a new element of that class is made, it will automatically get linked to that event. Handy, but not what I am after. I need to be able to assign these events when I load content from the server.

Comment: $.ajax has a callback function. Use it to perform whatever you need to do when you get your content back.

Answer (score 0):

You can get cleaner HTML code by making the event bindings in javascript. All you need are ways to identify the DOM objects for your HTML elements, like IDs.

If you have a link that has an ID "fooLink" you can do this in your JavaScript:

```
docuemnt.getElementById('foo').onclick = function () {
   //do your stuff here
}
```

This will have the same effect as binding the event in the "onclick" attribute if the link element in your HTML code.

That way, you can produce much cleaner HTML that is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you have missed the point of my problem. I know how how to use JavaScript to attach events to elements, but I need to be able to do this when I load content via AJAX

Comment: Ok, then you could wrap your event binding code into a function that you can re-call after loading new content to refresh your bindings. Or you just go with jQuerys "live()" as already mentioned.